# Redirect docker log messages into different syslog file (froward by logspout)

Tags: docker, logging, rsyslog

I have set up a host with some docker container, where logspout is used to forward all the logging to syslog:

```
docker run --name="logspout" -d \
  --restart=unless-stopped \
  --volume=/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  --log-opt tag="logspout" \
  gliderlabs/logspout \
  syslog://host-01.example.com:514
```

All the logs are in /var/log/syslog

I would like to split them up into files per container now, as it's getting to cluttered.

When I configure rsyslog to use a different file like this:

```
munin-server.*                  /var/log/munin.log
```

I get following messages in syslog:

```
May  9 12:44:39 docker-host-01 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="13893" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
May  9 12:44:39 docker-host-01 rsyslogd-2222: command 'KLogPermitNonKernelFacility' is currently not permitted - did you already set it via a RainerScript command (v6+ config)? [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2222 ]
May  9 12:44:39 docker-host-01 rsyslogd-2184: action 'munin-server' treated as ':omusrmsg:munin-server' - please use ':omusrmsg:munin-server' syntax instead, 'munin-server' will not be supported in the future [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2184 ]
May  9 12:44:39 docker-host-01 rsyslogd-3000: user name 'munin-se...' too long - ignored [v8.16.0]
May  9 12:44:39 docker-host-01 rsyslogd-2207: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/40-default.conf, on or before line 5: warnings occured in file '/etc/rsyslog.d/40-default.conf' around line 5 [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]
```

Is there a way to change the name (e.g. **munin-server**) somehow? Or is the message misleading?

Answer (score 0):

The legacy syntax you are using expects a [selector](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/sysklogd_format.html#selectors) of the form *facility.priority*, but the set of facilities is fixed and does not include arbitrary strings.

What you need is, for example, a legacy [property filter](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/filters.html#property-based-filters) as selector. It has the form *:property, [!]operation, "value"* followed by the action.

So you might try something like

```
:tag, isequal, "logspout"       /var/log/munin.log
```

if your option `-log-opt tag="logspout"` has the effect of setting the syslog tag property, or perhaps

```
:msg, contains, "munin-server"    /var/log/munin.log
```

or

```
:programname, startswith, "munin-server"    /var/log/munin.log
```

depending on where this string appears in the logged item. Ensure you start the selector in column 1.